# JQuery помогите разобраться

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помогите разобраться, в общем есть такой код

```
<div class="photo_m" id="ИД Любой"></div>
```

```js
$(".photo_m").mouseover(function(){
    $(".photo_m").css({"cursor":"pointer"});
    name_photo = $(".photo_m").attr('id');                
});
```

мне нужно узнать ID при наведении на `<div>`, в принципе это я сделал:

```
name_photo = $(".photo_m").attr('id');
```

вывожу — все ОК, но мне надо теперь использовать имя ID для обращения к нему. Как это сделать?
ну например  `name_photo = '16594623';`
как эта переменная вставляется в - `$()`
пробовал `$(name_photo)` - я так понял это не верно.

Comment: А зачем вам в данном конкретном случае вообще нужен `id`?

Comment: Я id буду в дальнейшем в базу передавать

Comment: Приведите пример разметки с реальным ID т.к. `ИД Любой` не является валидным (см. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute)

Comment: А еще неплохо было бы привести минимальный пример того, как вы пытаетесь получить элемент по id, который _не работает_.

Answer (score 2):

`$('#'+name_photo)` если я вас правильно понял.

Comment: не работает этот способ.

Comment: пробовал..........

Comment: Поясните тогда к чему вы хотите обратиться с помощью ID

Comment: Ну мне нужно использовать ID у меня ID не статический, а динамика. и при клике на элемент с классом NEW я должен выбрать из него ID. и потом использовать для дальнейшей передачи сценарию, наверное не совсем понятно?

Comment: Вот ID получен, что дальше с ним нужно сделать?

Comment: запихнуть $(сюда), ну или getElementById() чтобы с ним уже можно было работать, ну к примеру применить css

Comment: если нужен просто дом элемент можно его из event.target вытащить https://api.jquery.com/event.target/

Comment: да и $(this) по идее тоже должно работать если в итоге надо просто получить jquery объект элемента по которому провел мышкой

Answer (score 1):

В большинстве случаев:

```
$("#" + id)
```

В случае, если ты запихал в id пробелы, точки или другие символы, портящие css-селектор:

```
$(document.getElementById(id))
```

Оба варианта предполагают, что id уникальный в пределах страницы (как и должно быть).

Comment: То есть в $('#' + id) id может быть только строкой без . / и т.д.?

Comment: @Qwerity, еще, кстати, можно так `$("[id='invalid selector']")` ;-)

Comment: вот такую запись не видел))

Comment: @Максим, формально вроде бы да, но реально браузер съест любой. А вот id `abc.def` при превращении в селектор станет `#abc.def`, что означает элемент с id `abc` и классом `def` - а это явно не то, что ты ищешь.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, вариант с селектором по атрибуту подходит для случая с несколькими элементами с одинаковым id. Надеюсь, у автора всё же не тот случай.

Comment: Минус кто поставил, объясните, за что!

Comment: Ребят, тут написано все правильно, просто не под мой случай минусы ставить не надо(

Comment: var name_photo = $(this).attr('id');
                alert(name_photo);
                $('#'+name_photo).click(function(){alert();}); помогайте переписать.

Comment: я думаю все понимают о чем речь)

Comment: @Qwertiy, я не минусовал, но думаю это может быть связано с тем, что вы повторили ответ @HunterKiller. По существу: Вариант с селектором подходит для любого случая когда нельзя использовать формат `$('#id')`. Пробел (или точка) в ID это самый яркий пример такого случая. Формально он может быть не валиден, но в браузерах работает.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, в его ответе второй части нет. А без первой ответ был бы неполным.

Comment: @Максим, ты второй вариант проверил или нет? `$(document.getElementById(name_photo)).click(function(){alert();});` И покажи, какой у тебя id.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что id не может начинаться с цифры.

[htmlbook:](http://htmlbook.ru/html/attr/id)

> Идентификатор должен обязательно начинаться с латинского символа и может содержать в себе латинские буквы (A–Z, a–z), цифры (0–9), символ дефиса (-) и подчеркивания (_). Использование русских букв в именах идентификатора недопустимо.

Comment: Ну это я знаю, спасибо! меня интересует след.  вид  tr5463r1rss.img к примеру

Comment: @Максим Точки так же нельзя использовать

Comment: @Максим Можно попробовать класть id в атрибут data-id и далее использовать:
$("div[data-id='tr5463r1rss.img']]")

Comment: @Sasha_4ever, плохой у вас источник. В HTML5 можно использовать в качестве значения аттрибута id все что угодно, кроме пробела: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute (_The value ... must contain at least one character ... [and] ... must not contain any space characters._)

Comment: @Sasha_4ever, а в HTML4, формально нельзя,  но на практике браузеры нормально понимают ID, содержащие что-то отличное от `A-Za-z0-9_-`.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev согласен. Но `name_photo = '16594623';` все равно не подходит)

Comment: @Sasha_4ever, ошибаетесь. Этот ID валиден в HTML5 и работает на практике: http://jsfiddle.net/khsbofux/ (за кроссбраузерность не отвечаю). В одном вы правы, такие ID _не надо_ использовать.

Comment: var name_photo = $(".photo_m").attr('id');
var a = document.getElementById(name_photo);
a.click(function(){alert();});   так можно? в id = wjekhjkdj.png

Comment: @Максим, нельзя. Подсказка: объекты `HtmlElement` отличаются от результата выполнения функции `$('div')`.

Comment: получается чистым jq не выйдет. мешать с js надо, блин я уже часа 2 убил просто на ерунду

Comment: @Максим, а `jQuery` это не `JavaScript`?

Comment: Верно :D да я все понимаю что библиотека

Comment: и все же.... я перепробовал щас все о чем говорили ни один совет не работает я даже в id пишу одни a-z

Comment: Даже если эта информация не устарела, реально все браузеры замечательно обрабатывают любые id.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте data-атрибуты, их для этого и придумали.

```
<div class="photo_m" data-id="ИД Любой"></div>

$(".photo_m").mouseover(function(){
     var name_photo = $(this).data('id');
});
```

А cursor pointer лучше всего задать в стилях, а то слишком жирно для этого использовать jquery.