# jQ помогите разобрать создаю тему "2-раз"

Tags: jquery

Распишу все.

```
 $('#ed').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var height_dis = $(document).height();
    var widht_dis = $(document).width();
    $(".content").append("<div class='a'></div>");
    $(".a").css({'width':widht_dis,'height':height_dis, 'z-index':'100', 'background':'black', 'position':'fixed', 'top':'0', 'opacity':'0.5',});
    $(".content").append("<div class='b' ><img class='close_show_photo' src='views/social/img/fancy_close.png' width='30px' height='30px' /><ul><li><img class='photo_m' id='fczkmtpbua.jpg' src='views/profile/id1/photo/fczkmtpbua.jpg'/></li><li><img class='photo_m' id='wpujsxvwdv.jpg' src='views/profile/id1/photo/wpujsxvwdv.jpg'/></li><li><img class='photo_m' id='wurrbahxbu.jpg' src='views/profile/id1/photo/wurrbahxbu.jpg'/></li></ul></div>");          
    $(".photo_m").mouseover(function(){
       $(".photo_m").css({"cursor":"pointer"});

       $('#t')=attr('idl', 'id');
       $('#t').click(function(){alert();});

        });
        $(".a").click(function(){
            $(".a, .b").remove();
    });
    $(".close_show_photo").click(function(){
        $(".a, .b").remove();
    });
 });
```

В общем есть такой код, тут создание элемента на странице загрузка картинок, и т.д., мне что нужно. при клике на картинку, чтобы она выделилась бордером ну к примеру красным цветом. Далее у меня будет идти АЯКС и запись картинки которую быбрал я в базу то-есть id картинки. id картинки всегда динамический,а вот class статический, так вот как мне сделать чтобы по классу выбрать id? потом по этому выбранному id осуществить выделение элемента с этим id бордером. 
в общем мне нужно так, чтобы $(".КЛАСС") а стало $("#ИД"), и я уже мог его использовать.
Помогайте застрял на этом моменте.

Comment: Вместо создания нового вопроса, лучше бы отредактировали http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/449275/jquery-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F

Comment: А научиться выкладывать работоспособный пример вместо кусков кода - не вариант?

Comment: это уже работоспособный код.....

Comment: Максим, если ваш вопрос отмечен требующим правки — не нужно задавать его повторно. Вы пытаетесь обойти существующие правила и у вас это, конечно же, не получится. Лучше постарайтесь понять эти правила, отредактируйте вопрос и отвечайте на уточняющие вопросы в комментариях. Обязательно прочитайте эти разделы справки: [1](/help/mcve), [2](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Разметки-то нет, к которой он применяется.

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно получить id по классу, то вот так. Id - это ведь атрибут.

```
var = $('.class').attr('id');
```

И потом используете его как селектор

```
$('#'+var).css('border', '1px solid red');
```

Comment: А потом его использовать как? этот вариант я знаю он не работает

Comment: дополнил ответ: $('#'+var).css('border', '1px solid red');

Comment: не работает, пробовал, я с этим амном уже 2 дня долблюсь((

Comment: @ДмитрийНовиков, вы зря стараетесь. Автору уже был предложен этот вариант вот тут: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/449275/jquery-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F . Только, похоже, бестолку.

Comment: @ДмитрийНовиков, а `var`, кстати, ключевое слово в JavaScript.

Comment: ребят, я уже много чего перепробовал, большая проблема получить ID именно в функцию $()